# How to fix 'Properties Should Not Return Arrays' Warming when I have an Array Property in my JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a JSON data object and I pass that to my Controller using `([FromBody] Request request)` in my route.

```
public class Request
{
    public string[] Tests { get; set; }
}
```

But I get an error `61819Properties Should Not Return Arrays`

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx, it said `make the property a method or change the property to return a collection.`

My question is when I change the property to a Method, ASP.net won't create a JSON object from JSON data in POST body.  So what is the best way to fix this error for a JSON object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the option of taking the error's second suggestion, and making the property a collection instead, like this?

```
public List<string> Tests { get; set; }
```

Comment: That suggestion is actually `List<string> Tests { get; } = new List<string>();`, whether it works with JSON serialization I don't know, as it depends on the deserializer.

Comment: I don't understand why you suggest to add the instantiation, and remove the "set"?  I was trying to make the minimum required change to the original poster's code.

Comment: Because it is what [CA1819](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx) suggests, see the very last example on that page. And because of [CA2227: Collection properties should be read only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx).

Comment: I don't see how changing from returning an array to a list would make the code smell go away. The issue is returning a structure that is mutable, hence making the class vulnerable to lose its invariants.

Answer (score 3):

**The simple solution:**
As this not an error you can simply ignore it.

**The less simple solution:** All the `CAxxxx` warnings the visual studio spits out are `Static Code Analysis` warnings, which means the code still compiles, although by some code quality rules Microsoft has defined (All these CAs) you code is flawed. In many situations a property returning an array is a code smell, but as you pointed out yourself in this situation it is the way it needs to be done. So you can disable that warning using the [SuppressMessageAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1819:PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays")]
public string[] Tests { get; set; }
```